# Generate Evenly Distributed Pattern Based on Weights

Tags: arrays

I have an array of items $A = \{A_i\}, i \in I $ with integer weights $W_i, i \in I$. I need to build a function $f: I \rightarrow A $, that produces evenly distributed patterns of array elements predictable manner.

For example: an array of 3 elements: $A_1 = 1, A_2 = 2, A_3 = 3$ and weights: $W_1 = 1, W_2 = 2, W_3 = 2$. This means that pattern will consist of 5 repeating elements. One example of this pattern: $1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1$ (each iteration of 5 elements has exactly one 1, two 2's and two 3's).

What I need is the name of this problem to search for suitable algorithms. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The name of this problem is **weighted sampling without replacement**. One can search [the web](https://www.google.ca/search?q=weighted+sampling+without+replacement) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=weighted+sampling+without+replacement). [Not much result on this site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=weighted+sampling+without+replacement) yet.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize $W$ by calculating the greatest common divisor of $W$ and dividing every element by it.

Then just repeatedly iterate over $W$ in order, and if $W_i > 0$ subtract $1$ from it and output $A_i$. You stop when all $W_i = 0$.

If $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, \dots $ in your example is also fine then just output $W_i$ copies of $A_i$ after normalization.